# Is there a way to get expressions to output in terms of Log2 instead of Log?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, output-formatting

I'm in computer science, pretty much every logarithm I ever encounter is base 2.

Normally, Mathematica wants to convert every logarithm to the natural log `Log`, so an expression like `Log2[x]` will output as `Log[x]/Log[2]`.

Is there a way to output an expression in terms of `Log2` instead?

Comment: Try using `SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTwoArgumentLog" -> False]`

Comment: @CarlWoll do you know if there's a way to set this as the default for new notebooks? I pretty much never want natural logs.